# How to replace img src with jquery for different window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

Really struggling with this one. I'm trying to replace the img src for different window widths (responsive design) and I cant get it to work. It works ok if I use `$(window).resize()` but that will only change the image src on actual window resizing dragging the browser window back and fourth.

What I cant get it to do is use the desired img src on load regardless of resizing the browser window. I know this is a bit confusing so my code below will explain what I'm trying to do a bit better. Would really appreciate the help on this one!

```
$(function(){
        if($(window).width() >= 0 && $(window).width() <= 400){
           $("img").attr("src","small.jpg");
        }
        else if($(window).width() > 400 && $(window).width() <= 768){
           $("img").attr("src","medium.jpg"); 
        }
        else{
           $("img").attr("src","large.jpg"); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't really see why your code shouldn't work as it is now...

Comment: I know i've been staring at it for hours looking for little mistakes but it just wont work! It will only load my standard img src that is in my html. Images will change if i use `$(window).resize()` instead of `$(function())` but i dont want to have to drag the browser around to force the images to change if you know what i mean.

Comment: Any reason why you are doing this via JS instead of CSS `@media` declarations? Is it so that you don't have to scale down your images?

Comment: Exactly that plus using `@media` i'm having to use background images and setting `height` and `width` which messes up the responsiveness of the images unless you know a better way?

Comment: As expected, it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/ta7fss9d/1/  You're doing something else wrong, that code is correct and working.

Comment: A.Rama it is working! Ur a legend thanks for convincing me I was right in the first place! I bet i didn't FTP my file back to the server or something stupid :-). Thanks for your help dude. i cant vote your answer though as its a comment?? i'm new to this by the way!!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have it working with $(window).resize(), you can try triggering the resize event when the document is loaded.

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that doesnt work either. Theres something im missing!

Answer (score 0):

OK, got this working. The code was right all along i'm just stupid and and didn't FTP my files back to the server!!! Thanks for helping guys really appreciate it.
At least people know how to do this now with out using `@media` to use different images per screen size!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a slight alternative to the original post to change image source because I'm also doing a couple other things on page resize that I didn't want to do using @media.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 1130) {
            $('#logo').attr("src", "large.jpg");
        }
        else {
            $('#logo').attr("src", "small.jpg");
        }
    });
```

Since I have a couple other changes to make on resize (for navigation menu) I can list everything in the if/else.